# How Can I Get User's LinkedIn Profile Url using Linkedin API

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have the first name , last name and company name of a user. How can I get the Linkedin profile url of that user? Using The Linkedin API
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work , just change your onLinkedInAuth method into this

```
function onLinkedInAuth()
{
IN.API.Profile("me")
.fields("firstName", "lastName", "industry", "location:(name)", "picture-url", "headline", "summary", "num-connections", "public-profile-url", "distance", "positions", "email-address", "educations", "date-of-birth")
.result(displayProfiles)
.error(displayProfilesErrors);
}
```